# oracle 12c enterprise manager default login

Tags: oracle-12c, windows, logins

I am just installed oracle database in my windows machine after installation it i can't able to login i dont have username only i know password . can any body help on this

advance thanks   [image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just uninstall it and install it again?

Comment: @TonyHinkle is there any other way.?

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/899559?start=0&tstart=0 maybe?